# Sorting a Wicket DataTable by a PropertyColumn that contains some null values

Tags: sorting, datatable, null, wicket

Here is some psuedo code for my table:

```
List<IColumn<Foo>> columns = new ArrayList<IColumn<Foo>>();
columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Foo>(Model.of("Name"), "name", "name"));
columns.add(new PropertyColumn<Foo>(Model.of("Leader"), "leader.lastName",
   leader.fullName"));

fooTable = new AjaxFallbackDefaultDataTable<Foo>("fooTable", columns,
   provider, 10);
```

The class Foo contains among other fields:

```
private String name;
private User leader;
```

And class User contains Strings userName, password, firstName, lastName, email, along with:

```
public String getFullName() {
    // Use blank strings in place of "null" literals
    String f = firstName != null ? firstName: "";
    String l = lastName != null ? lastName: "";
    return (l + ", " + f);
}
```

Every Foo has a name, and every User has has a first and last name.  However, not every Foo has a leader, so in the table above, there are several null/ blank values for leader.  When the table is sorted by leader by clicking the column header, all Foo's without a leader are missing.  When sorted again by name, they return, with blanks for leader.

Is there anyway to fix this?  A preference where nulls always sort last would be best, but I'll take anything where they don't just disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct sorting is a responsibility of the `SortableDataProvider`. If it is making items disappear, you should revise it's logic.

Comment: Alright, but technically, my provider calls my DAO, and it was the DAO's fault.  So suddenly this changed from a Wicket question to a Hibernate question, but I figured that part out.  In any event, it looks fixed.  So thanks.

Comment: @cobaltduck I'm having the same issue, could you elaborate on your solution. What changes did you make?

Comment: @JJT - Note that the dates here are 5.5 years old, and I am no longer assigned to this project- nor even working at the same company.  What I remember though, was that the wicket data provider called some Hibernate DAO method that returned a List<Foo>, and that DAO method was not including leader-less Foo's in that List in all cases when it should have been.  So the solution was to fix *that* method, not to fix the wicket thing.

Comment: @cobaltduck Thanks for the quick reply, appreciated. This makes things a little clearer for me.